# JavaScript functions broke my page jumps?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to develop a personal website and running into some issues. At the top of my page I had a horizontal table that contained 6 different images (buttons) that linked to different sections of the page.

I wanted to spice up the buttons with JavaScript and make the image of the button change onMouseOver and onMouseOut so I found a way to do so online with some JavaScript but the problem now is that the buttons no longer jump to the appropriate section of the page when using Google Chrome or Safari, but in IE 9 they still do work correctly...

Here is my old code that worked properly:

```
<html>
...
<body>
<center>
<table border="1" style="color:#D80000;text-align:center">
<tr>
<td>
<a href="#about"><img src="images/aboutMe.png" alt="About Me"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#courses"><img src="images/courseList.png" alt="Courses"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#work"><img src="images/workHistory.png" alt="Work History"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#places"><img src="images/placesBeen.png" alt="Places I've Been"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#games"><img src="images/gamesPlay.png" alt="Games I Play"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#contact"><img src="images/contactMe.png" alt="Contact"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my new code that is now broken:

```
<html>
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (document.images)
{
 <!-- Preload original Images -->
 var about_init= new Image();
 about_init.src="images/aboutMe.png";
 var courses_init= new Image();
 courses_init.src="images/courseList.png";
 var work_init= new Image();
 work_init.src="images/workHistory.png";
 var places_init= new Image();
 places_init.src="images/placesBeen.png";
 var games_init= new Image();
 games_init.src="images/gamesPlay.png";
 var contact_init= new Image();
 contact_init.src="images/contactMe.png";

 <!--Preload images for mouseover -->
 var about_new= new Image();
 about_new.src="images/aboutAlt.png"; 
 var courses_new= new Image();
 courses_new.src="images/courseAlt.png";
 var work_new= new Image();
 work_new.src="images/workAlt.png";
 var places_new= new Image();
 places_new.src="images/placesAlt.png";
 var games_new= new Image();
 games_new.src="images/gamesAlt.png";
 var contact_new= new Image();
 contact_new.src="images/contactAlt.png";
}

function change_it(the_name)
{
 if (document.images)
 {
  document.images[the_name].src= eval(the_name+"_new.src");
 }
}

function change_back(the_name)
{
 if (document.images)
 {
  document.images[the_name].src= eval(the_name+"_init.src");
 }
}
//-->
</script>
</head>

<body>
...
<center>
<table border="1" style="color:#D80000;text-align:center">
<tr>
<td>
<a href="#about" onMouseOver="change_it('about')" onMouseOut="change_back('about')"><img src="images/aboutMe.png" name="about" id="about" border="0" alt="About Me"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#courses" onMouseOver="change_it('courses')" onMouseOut="change_back('courses')"><img src="images/courseList.png" name="courses" id="courses" border="0" alt="Courses"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#work" onMouseOver="change_it('work')" onMouseOut="change_back('work')"><img src="images/workHistory.png" name="work" id="work" border="0" alt="Work History"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#places" onMouseOver="change_it('places')" onMouseOut="change_back('places')"><img src="images/placesBeen.png" name="places" id="places" border="0" alt="Places I've Been"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#games" onMouseOver="change_it('games')" onMouseOut="change_back('games')"><img src="images/gamesPlay.png" name="games" id="games" border="0" alt="Games I Play"></a>
</td>
<td>
<a href="#contact" onMouseOver="change_it('contact')" onMouseOut="change_back('contact')"><img src="images/contactMe.png" name="contact" id="contact" border="0" alt="Contact"></a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
...
</body>
</html>
```

The images properly switch when the mouse is moved over/off them, but the jump to the corresponding page sections seems to be broken, it seems like they're all jumping to the #about section now. Once again, the weirder thing is that this is only the case when I'm using Google Chrome on my laptop running Windows 7 or Safari using my iPhone 4 but when I use the new Internet Explorer 9 on my laptop running Windows 7 all the buttons still link correctly.

Any idea what's breaking the links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id's on your new code images might be confusing the browser where the links should jump to, since they are the same as the #id on your links.

Comment: Thank you! After removing the id's in my new code the buttons all link correctly now!

Comment: @Mark: Glad to help.  When an answer solves the problem, please mark it accepted (checkbox underneath the vote counter in upper-left).  You want to make a habit of doing this on all questions, as it lets others know what the correct answer was, and encourages people to answer your other questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Like mellamokb said, the ids and names of your images confuse the browser. You can simply change either the anchors name or the ids and names of your images.

But I think you should consider using the :hover css pseudo-class which is now supported by all the major browsers : http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/sel_hover.asp

Comment: I agree... why use inline javascript when you can more easily do image changes with CSS

Comment: I took a look at the link you posted but I didn't see anything there about using :hover to change an image, only text attributes. I found another link online that showed an example of how to use :hover to change an image but it was a bit confusing to me and since by removing the ids for my images I solved the problem I think I'm going to leave it as is for now since it's working.

@iWasRobbed I'm new to web development/design, I've never learned JavaScript or CSS, only a very small amount of HTML so I'm unfamiliar with a lot of methods of doing reasonably simple things.